# How to use Spring Security roles without auth0

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jwt, auth0

We have a Spring application with auth0 Authorization/Authentication mechanism based on JWT, which manages user roles by auth0. We have some cases where we need to change user roles during his session, that's why we decide to use internal Roles management based on the spring-security instead of auth0. But we want to stay with auth0 only for Authentication.

Is it a normal way to do?

How to handle requests with auth0 user details and add necessary authorities?

Comment: This is very easy to do, but depending on context there are several different possible implementation approaches. Also, ensure you have a very good reason for not letting Auth0 take care of your authentication / authorization concerns directly - Auth0 offers the flexibility to integrate externally for authorization but has comprehensive, best of class built-in capabilities that you would lose out on leveraging.